# PHP contest Logical

Tags: php

In one of my web application in php there is a contest section . It contains a multiple choice 10 questions , Each has 4 options .

After user filling the form I am saving the answer as comma separated values in a db . like follows:

```
user   |    answer
-------------------------------------
112    |  1,7,8,9,8,5,2,3,6,7,9,6
```

I got a answer key same as the use's filled answer key ..

What is the best logical method for evaluate the users input and find out the highest scored user?

Comment: The best way is to not store the data that way...

Comment: Comma-separated values...in a database? Please don't shoot yourself in the foot... use multiple, linked tables instead (as per the [Relational Database Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database).)

Comment: +1 to SpikeX. Storing multiple values like this in a single column isn't even 1NF. You are going to end up with any number of headaches down the road if you want to change the number of questions.

Comment: Can be a little more specific? Not really sure what you mean here "It contains a multiple choice 10 questions , Each has 4 options ." Just give some real examples so that we can understand what exactly you are doing

Comment: OK guyz ... thanks for the reply and I altered my answer table to following columns like id,user_id,question_id,contest_id with relationships ...

But now I wonder how to validate/evaluate the answers with correct answers and find out the winner(s)

Comment: @Josh Strange please see this
http://www.w3schools.com/quiztest/quiztest.asp?qtest=PHP

Comment: If each answer has 4 options, why are there numbers greater than 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this isn't the best way to store data, but I'd evaluate like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from `table` where 1",CONNECTION_IDENTIFIER) or die("die message");
 $answer_key = array(answer1,answer2,etc);
 $high_score = 0;
 $high_scorer= "";
 while($r=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $users_answers = explode(',',$r['answer']);
    $user_score = 0;
    for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
        if ($answer_key[$i]==$users_answers[$i]){
            $user_score++;
        }
    }
     if ($user_score > $high_score){
            $high_score =  $user_score;
            $high_scorer = $r['user'];
     }
 }

 echo "High scorer is $high_scorer with $high_score points";
```

Comment: thanks for the reply and this one seems to be what I am looking for ... Thanks .. I will go through it . . BTW how to increase the execution time of this function .. in case of more and more answers ?

Comment: This solution should be fine for up to several thousand users. If you're expecting much more than that you'll want to take a different approach... but honestly, given than you only have 10,000 possible combinations (10^4) the chances that you won't have several people ace the test once you have 50K+ respondents is extremely small... maybe add some code above this that checks if anyone has aced it (compare the answer key string to the user key string... chances are that a few people will match once you have lots of respondents)... if there are matches then skip the looping

Comment: Also, if that didn't work, you could also add a column to your answers table and store users' scores as they add the answers (once they hit submit, it runs the comparison functions and stores their entry like:
user: 1322, answers: 1,4,7,2,5,1,5,5,2,8, score: 8
and then use use a mysql "ORDER BY" or MAX() function to get the best scores...  this would allow you to process scores over the entire time the survey was up rather than all at once.

Answer (score 1):

if you have answers with scores like that:

$answersRating = array(1 => 0, 2=> 1, 3 => 3, 4 => 2, ....) when selecting answer 1 he got 0 points, for 2  => one point, for 3 => 3 points and so on. You can do something like that:

```
$score = array_sum(array_intersect_key($answersRating, array_flip(explode(',', $userAnswersStringFromDB))));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should structure your DB like this:
NOTE: This is bare minimum, you of course would add extra fields to questions like name, description, etc

```
answers   | id, user_id, question_id, answer
questions | id, contest_id, correct_answer
user      | id, name
```

Then you could get everything with a query.

Top Score:

```
SELECT u.name,count(*) as Score FROM user u, answers a, questions q WHERE u.id=a.user_id and q.id = a.question_id and q.correct_answer=a.answer WHERE q.contest_id=XXX ORDER BY Score
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply and .... I had a doubt that ... you mean the answer row in the answers table as a comma separated values like ( 1,4,2,4,1,3,4 ) . Please help